# Set seaborn relplot legend - hue values

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the analysis with only 3 values in dataframe which are set for relplot "hue" parameter, but seaborn plots some auto-range hue legend with five values. How I can specify exact values?

```
sns.relplot(x='x', y='y', 
         hue = 'hue', style='style',
         kind='scatter', size = 'size', 
         data=df2)
```

```html
          size style  hue   col             y             x
8     3.717546   1:1   50   715  1.930280e+06  4.932825e+06
24    7.165478   1:2   50   715  1.712680e+06  7.112875e+06
40    5.357067   2:1   50   715  1.148624e+06  2.494125e+06
56    2.758713   1:1   50   715  1.766268e+06  3.196175e+06
72    3.402869   1:2   50   715  9.385742e+05  4.046025e+06
88    3.160937   2:1   50   715  9.856859e+05  1.585155e+06
104   4.094309   1:1  250   715  8.416346e+06  7.944250e+07
120  39.287651   1:2  250   715  6.217049e+06  1.352370e+08
132   1.625882   1:1    5   715  5.055178e+04  5.062150e+04
148  35.241220   2:1  250   715  6.171461e+06  4.046025e+07
164   2.071234   1:1  250   715  6.038509e+06  2.697350e+07
180  13.498847   1:2  250   715  4.636012e+06  4.951300e+07
196   9.499857   2:1  250   715  4.012017e+06  1.322810e+07
212   4.166135   1:1    5  1545  6.218541e+05  6.244550e+05
228   4.979377   1:2    5  1545  6.864812e+05  7.316100e+05
244   4.127152   2:1    5  1545  3.558532e+05  3.565675e+05
257   2.516927   1:2    5   715  5.884268e+04  5.893525e+04
271   4.942125   1:1    5  1545  4.836641e+05  4.840450e+05
```

so, there are 3 different values for, "style", "hue" and "col" and the legend shows values that never appeared in the df2, At least I would like to fix hue legend to there values: [5, 50, 250]

[image: this is how plot looks]

Comment: Hello @dvulin, I would suggest adding more details to your question. Currently it does not allow the reader to understand your issue. Try putting what you did, what you got vs what you were expecting.

Comment: I get `[5, 50, 250]` for hue when I run the code, because there are only 3 values in the sample.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `seaborn` thinks that hue is a continuous variable. You need to change that. One way is to change the dataframe, for example, by converting the hue column to strings.

```
df['hue'] = df['hue'].map(lambda x: str(x))
```

Alternatively, one may enforce  `seaborn` to treat "hue" as a categorical random variable directly (but it acts glitchy in my experience). Please insert to `relplot` keywords.

```
hue_order = np.unique(df['hue'])
```

Comment: thank you, (I've tried something similar as "glitchy" example, i.e. I hardcoded hue_order = [5, 50, 250]) but it seems it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about that. That's why I call it glitchy :) The first method works anyway.